# Valor do input type null

Tags: php, html

Vou passar aqui toda página para uma análise e saber como que eu envio o valor da input type para a outra página. Desde já agradeço!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>

<body>


<form action="carrinho_vitrine.php" method="post">

<!--INFORMAÇÕES DO PRODUTO -->

<table id="tb_vitrine" border="1px solid black" bordercolor="f2f2f2" width=90% align="center" class="bordasimples">
 <caption><h4>:: Informações do Produto ::</h4></caption>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['cbo_vitrine'])){  

//Conecta o banco de dados e traz as informações dos produtos...
include("conexao.php");
$pdo=conectar();          
    try{     

$refer = $_POST['cbo_vitrine'];

           //Buscando dados..  
           $sql=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM vitrine_1 WHERE refer = '$refer'");
              $sql->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
              $sql->bindParam(':refer', $_GET['refer'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $sql->bindParam(':modelo', $_GET['modelo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $sql->bindParam(':cor', $_GET['cor'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $sql->bindParam(':numeracao', $_GET['numeracao'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $sql->bindParam(':unit', $_GET['unit'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

              $sql->execute(array('refer' => $refer));

              //criando o cabeçalho na tabela
               echo '<th>' .'REFERÊNCIA'. '</th>';
                echo '<th>' .'MODELO'. '</th>';
                 echo '<th>' .'COR'. '</th>';
                  echo '<th>' .'NUMERAÇÃO'. '</th>';
                   echo '<th>' .'QTDE'. '</th>';
                    echo '<th>' .'PREÇO UNIT.'. '</th>';

              //loop
              while($linha=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                          //pegando o dado do campo = refer 
                            $id = $linha["id"];
                            $refer = $linha["refer"];                         
                            $modelo = $linha["modelo"];
                            $cor = $linha["cor"];
                            $numeracao = $linha["numeracao"];
                            $qtde = "1";
                            $unit = $linha["unit"];                    

                           //montando a table...
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' .  $refer . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .  $modelo . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .  $cor . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .  $numeracao . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .  $qtde . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .  $unit . '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';               
                };

echo'<td height="10"><a href="carrinho_vitrine.php?acao=add&id='.$id.'">
<img src="img/comprar-1.png" name="add_car_vitrine" id="add_car_vitrine" height="50" width="120" align="center" title="Adicionar ao Carrinho" value="add_car_vitrine"></a></td>';

 //fechando a conexão
 $pdo = null;
               }
catch(PDOExcception $erro){
echo $erro->getmessage();
                          }
}
?>  

</table> 

Sua numeração:
<input type="text" value="" id="numero" maxlength="2" placeholder="Digite" size="3" align="center">

</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Com jquery eu estou testando e estou capturando o valor da input type.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 

   $("#add_car_vitrine").click(function(){

     var valor = $("input[name=numero]").val();

       if($("#numero").val()==""){ 
         alert("Digite sua numeração!");
         return false; 
       }                
       //mostramos o valor com alert()
       //alert(valor);
   });
});
```

Tem como montar um Ajax e enviar para a outra página o valor dessa input type?
Alguém pode postar um exemplo por gentileza?
Grato.

Answer (score 1):

> Já que a pergunta foi editada, a resposta também foi editada e passa a ser:

1. Essa linha não pode estar dentro do `if(isset($_POST['cbo_vitrine'])){` porque dessa forma não vai aparecer para que seja clicada:

   ```
   <img src="img/comprar-1.png" name="add_car_vitrine" id="add_car_vitrine" height="50" width="120" align="center" title="Adicionar ao Carrinho" value="add_car_vitrine"></a></td>';
   ```
2. Para que seja funcional coloque-a antes da tag de fechamento `</form>` como `button`:

   ```
   ..........
   ..........
   <?php
   echo'<td height="10"><button type="button" id="add_car_vitrine">
   <img src="img/comprar-1.png" height="50" width="120" align="center" title="Adicionar ao Carrinho"></button></td>';
   ?>
   </form>
   ```
3. Coloque um id na tag `form` exemplo: `id="myForm"`

   ```
   <form id="myForm" action="carrinho_vitrine.php" method="post">
   ```
4. O script - no else coloque o envio do formulario `$('#myForm').submit();`

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 

       $("#add_car_vitrine").click(function(){

       var valor = $("input[name=numero]").val();

         if($("#numero").val()==""){ 
            alert("Digite sua numeraçao!");
            return false; 
         }else{
            $('#myForm').submit();
         }                 
         //mostramos o valor com alert()
         //alert(valor);
      });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi sua pergunta. Onde vc colocou esse echo?
Se for no form, sua expressão pode ficar dessa forma:

```
<form method="post" action="teste.php?pag=<?php echo $pag; ?>">
...
```

Comment: Nada funcionou, infelizmente... O que percebí é que enviando desta forma: <a href="carrinho_vitrine.php?acao=add&id='.$id.'">, então estou enviand via GET, Correto?

Comment: Neste inpu type  -->> Sua numeração:
<input type="text" value="" id="numero" maxlength="2" placeholder="Digite" size="3" align="center">, eu quero enviar para a outra página. Observe que este dado: echo '<td>' .  $numeracao . '</td>';  ele vem da base. Quando digito o novo valor no input type, eu estou alterando ao enviar para a outra página. Só que isso não acontece.